# GIS layers created using FME 2021 not visible in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, ogr2ogr, sql-server, fme-form

QGIS 3.24
SQL Server 2015

I have GIS layers in SQL Server created using ogr2ogr and FME2021
All the layers are created using my machine.

In my QGIS Desktop I can see all layers irrespective of how they are created. However, my colleagues can't see the layers created using FME 2021. They can only see the layers created using ogr2ogr. They are using the same version of QGIS (3.24) as mine.
I checked geometry_columns table in SQL Server database. It only lists layers created by ogr2ogr.

If we need to list/register the layers created by FME 2021 in geometry_columns, then how we do that and why can I see all layers including those created using FME 2021 in my QGIS desktop even though they are not registered with geometry_columns tables?

I searched all previous related posts, but found that my case is bit different.

Comment: Check your permissions. Are you using the same user in FME to connect as you are in QGIS? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195809/why-would-fme-imported-data-into-sql-server-not-being-found-by-qgis (question has too many variables currently)

Comment: Yes they are the same user. I am the one who created those layers using FME and Ogr2ogr using my desktop machine. I have no problem with my QGIS; can see all layers   in QGIS. Problem is with my colleagues who have connect and select permission on the sql server database (database level permission). They can only see the layers created using ogr2ogr not the one using FME.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the option "Only look in the geometry_columns metadata table" is **UNCHECKED**

OGR when uploading content will add an entry to the geometry_columns table, but as far as I am aware FME MS SQL Server writer will not. This would explain why your users can see the OGR layers but not the FME layers.

IMO it would be best to maintain an update to date geometry_columns table for your QGIS users. One method to do this is via a stored procedure that can be called in SQL Management studio or from within FME to keep the geometry_columns table up to date. https://gist.github.com/christippett/9fd0a4b8e6d01b2c34395103ae1c4d66

[image]